# $_POST with DOM element dotted name

Tags: php, forms

I have a select element whose name is dotted (e.g. `name = "select.first"`) and I have troubles getting its value with `$_POST['select.first']`.
Is it because of the dotted name? Is there a way of fixing this while keeping the dotted name?

Comment: `ID` and `NAME` tokens must begin with a letter (`[A-Za-z]`) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits (`[0-9]`), hyphens (`"-"`), underscores (`"_"`), colons (`":"`), and periods (`"."`). Your name attribute is fine. Can you post the output of `var_dump($_POST)`?

Comment: `var_dump($_POST]` and you will see how it is saved exactly

Comment: try to use a backslash before the dot '\' or a forwardslash '/'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the HTML specs

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
> followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
> underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

So it's perfectly valid in HTML. PHP converts names with `.` to `_` as detailed in the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php).

> Dots and spaces in variable names are converted to underscores. For example  becomes $_REQUEST["a_b"].

This is the default behaviour, i'm not sure there's a way around it except to either use underscore on both the server and client or to use `.` on the client and `_` on the server.
I would use the former for consistency sake.

Comment: Didn't know of the conversion! the problem was that the `.` is converted to `_`, so the PHP has to be `$_POST['select_first']` even if the name of the object is dotted (`name="select.first"`).